# Grabbing and sending elements from MongoDB in Node.js server response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, synchronous

In my Express route, I am trying to return a list of elements that I am grabbing from MongoDB using Mongoose.  I'm basically iterating through an array of items, and making MongoDB calls to get the parameter objects that each item has.  However, I'm having trouble making sure that I get all the parameters before I send the response.  I've tried using promises, other async library functions, etc, but none of them have seemed to work.

The current iteration of the code looks like this (I have tried a lot of different things):

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res){
  Flow.find({}, function(err, items) {
    console.log(items);
    var payload = {}
    var params = [];

    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var count2 = 0;
      async.whilst(
        function() {
          return ((items[i]) && (count2 < items[i].params.length));
        },
        function(callback) {
          Parameter.findById(items[i].params[count2], function(err, out) {
            params.push(out);
            count2++;
            callback();
          });
        },
        function(err) {
          console.log(params);
          var payload = {
            "flows": items,
            "params": params
          };

          res.send(payload);
          console.log('success: flows found');
        }
      );
    }
```

This code sends a payload with params not being completely full.

What would be a good way to deal with this?  Honestly I just want these database calls to be synchronous, but I just can't figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Aside from other issues, all of these queries result to simply finding by `_id', so can you not just issue one query with the `$in` operator containing a list of those `_id` values instead? That would be one query, and not seeing why you need many queries to do this.

Comment: oh wow I didn't even know that was possibility. i'll still need to iterate through the items array to make up that list (but it won't require repeated database calls). i'll try doing that inside an async loop then and see how that works tomorrow.

but, i still don't quite understand why this doesn't work...

Comment: Well not everything is inside your async whilst and therefore waiting on callback completion before sending. But the process should not be necessary as there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really seem necessary as you can actually use the [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator with all the  results from your first query:

```
Flow.find({},function(err,items) {

    var ids = [];

    // blocking? yes, but should be minor - do better if there are problems
    for ( var i=0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
       for ( var n=0; n < items[i].params.length; n++ ) {
           ids.push( items[i].params[n] );
       }
    }

    Parameter.find({ "_id": { "$in": ids } },function(err,params) {
        res.send({ "flows": items, "params": params });
    });

});
```

So there should be no reason to execute multiple queries inside an async loop, or loops as your code seems to be missing as the direct cause of the problem there.

Comment: thanks -- this worked perfectly. just as a follow-up: is it likely that there could be so many ids/params such that the find gets sent before the ids array is fully populated?  in that case, should I just use async.waterfall or something?